# Scale national economic data down to a watershed

Tags: watershed, water

Economic Input Output databases such as e.g. the [World Input-Output Database](http://www.wiod.org/project) by the European Commission contain economic (and often environmental) statistics. The spatial resolution of data provided in these databases is usually given on a country level e.g. "the turnover of the agricultural sector in the Netherlands per year is X milion €". I would like to link national trade data to individual watersheds. However obviosuly, the boundaries of a watershed rarely coincide with the political boundaries of a country. Does anyone have an idea/a suggestion, how I can relate national economic data to individual watersheds within the respective country?

Comment: You'd need to know the locations of all the facilities involved with the economic output in order to apportion the values correctly. Otherwise you are stuck with evenly distributing value to all polygons by area.

Comment: or comparing different downscaling scenarios e.g. by amount of watersheds within a country, by watershed area ... possibly more?